# How to remove 2 or more duplicates from list and maintain their initial order?

Tags: scala

Lets assume we have a Scala list:

```
val l1 = List(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 5, 1)
```

We can easily remove duplicates using the following code:

```
l1.distinct
```

or

```
l1.toSet.toList
```

But what if we want to remove duplicates only if there are more than 2 of them? So if there are more than 2 elements with the same value we remain only two and remove the rest of them.

I could achieve it with following code:

```
l1.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.take(2)).values.toList.flatten
```

that gave me the result:

```
List(2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 3, 3)
```

Elements are removed but the order of remaining elements is different from how these elements appeared in the initial list. How to do this operation and remain the order from original list?

So the result for l1 should be:

```
List(1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 5)
```

Comment: Do you prefer folding or recursion? If you keep the state of the already seen fields with their number, you just need to filter out those values that already occurred too often.

Comment: I do not prefer folding or recursion. If there are many different answers I want to see them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not the most efficient.

```
scala> val l1 = List(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 5, 1)
l1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 5, 1)

scala> l1.zipWithIndex.groupBy( _._1 ).map(_._2.take(2)).flatten.toList.sortBy(_._2).unzip._1
res10: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 5)
```

Answer (score 7):

My humble answer:

```
def distinctOrder[A](x:List[A]):List[A] = {
    @scala.annotation.tailrec
    def distinctOrderRec(list: List[A], covered: List[A]): List[A] = {
       (list, covered) match {
         case (Nil, _) => covered.reverse
         case (lst, c) if c.count(_ == lst.head) >= 2 => distinctOrderRec(list.tail, covered)
         case _ =>  distinctOrderRec(list.tail, list.head :: covered)
       }
    }
    distinctOrderRec(x, Nil)
}
```

With the results:

```
scala> val l1 = List(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 5, 1)
l1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 5, 1)

scala> distinctOrder(l1)
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 5)
```

*On Edit: Right before I went to bed I came up with this!*

```
l1.foldLeft(List[Int]())((total, next) => if (total.count(_ == next) >= 2) total else total :+ next)
```

With an answer of:

```
res9: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 5)
```

Answer (score 6):

Not the prettiest.  I look forward to seeing the other solutions.

```
def noMoreThan(xs: List[Int], max: Int) =
{
  def op(m: Map[Int, Int], a: Int) = {
    m updated (a, m(a) + 1)
  }
  xs.scanLeft( Map[Int,Int]().withDefaultValue(0) ) (op).tail
    .zip(xs)
    .filter{ case (m, a) => m(a) <= max }
    .map(_._2)
}

scala> noMoreThan(l1, 2)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 5)
```

Comment: I am glad we provided different angles. :) (I have borrowed your `max` parameter. Hope you do not mind.)

Comment: I added your withDefaultValue.  Now I'm thinking with scalaz we could foldMap to good effect. EDIT: actually I guess we'd need something like scanMap. EDIT2: writing a scanMap using home-made monoids and functors would be fun, might do that tonight.

Answer (score 6):

More straightforward version using foldLeft:

```
l1.foldLeft(List[Int]()){(acc, el) => 
     if (acc.count(_ == el) >= 2) acc else el::acc}.reverse
```

Comment: Ah, I see Daniel also has this. The prepend-then-reverse should make this a bit more efficient.

Comment: These solutions using `count` can be quite inefficient (O(n^2)).

Comment: Yes, they can. It depends on the OP's context if this is a problem. They're also clear, which is also a good thing.

Answer (score 5):

Similar to how distinct is implemeted, with a multiset instead of a set:

```
def noMoreThan[T](list : List[T], max : Int) = {
    val b = List.newBuilder[T]
    val seen = collection.mutable.Map[T,Int]().withDefaultValue(0)
    for (x <- list) {
      if (seen(x) < max) {
        b += x
        seen(x) += 1
      }
    }
    b.result()
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on experquisite's answer, but using `foldLeft`:

```
def noMoreThanBis(xs: List[Int], max: Int) = {
  val initialState: (Map[Int, Int], List[Int]) = (Map().withDefaultValue(0), Nil)
  val (_, result) = xs.foldLeft(initialState) { case ((count, res), x) =>
    if (count(x) >= max)
      (count, res)
    else
      (count.updated(x, count(x) + 1), x :: res)
  }
  result.reverse
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`distinct` is defined for `SeqLike` as

```
/** Builds a new $coll from this $coll without any duplicate elements.
 *  $willNotTerminateInf
 *
 *  @return  A new $coll which contains the first occurrence of every element of this $coll.
 */
def distinct: Repr = {
  val b = newBuilder
  val seen = mutable.HashSet[A]()
  for (x <- this) {
    if (!seen(x)) {
      b += x
      seen += x
    }
  }
  b.result()
}
```

We can define our function in very similar fashion:

```
def distinct2[A](ls: List[A]): List[A] = {
  val b = List.newBuilder[A]
  val seen1 = mutable.HashSet[A]()
  val seen2 = mutable.HashSet[A]()
  for (x <- ls) {
    if (!seen2(x)) {
      b += x
      if (!seen1(x)) {
        seen1 += x
      } else {
        seen2 += x
      }
    }
  }
  b.result()
}

scala> distinct2(l1)
res4: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 5)
```

This version uses internal state, but is still pure. It is also quite easy to generalise for arbitrary *n* (currently 2), but specific version is more performant.

You can implement the same function with folds carrying the "what is seen once and twice" state with you. Yet the for loop and mutable state does the same job.

Comment: This test fails for the above, distinct2[Long](List(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 2, 5, 2, 3, 4, 9, 1, -1))
But anyways this looks like the right direction to go. 
P.S : Output was  List(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3, 4, 9, -1).

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
list
 .zipWithIndex
 .groupBy(_._1)
 .toSeq
 .flatMap { _._2.take(2) }       
 .sortBy(_._2)
 .map(_._1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Its a bit ugly, but its relatively faster

```
val l1 = List(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 5, 1)
l1.foldLeft((Map[Int, Int](), List[Int]())) { case ((m, ls), x) => {
  val z = m + ((x, m.getOrElse(x, 0) + 1))
  (z, if (z(x) <= 2) x :: ls else ls)
}}._2.reverse
```

Gives: `List(1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 5)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive solution (it will stack overflow for large lists):

```
  def filterAfter[T](l: List[T], max: Int): List[T] = {
    require(max > 1)
    //keep the state of seen values
    val seen = Map[T, Int]().withDefaultValue(0)//init to 0
    def filterAfter(l: List[T], seen: Map[T, Int]): (List[T], Map[T, Int]) = {
      l match {
        case x :: xs =>
          if (seen(x) < max) {
            //Update the state and pass to next
            val pair = filterAfter(xs, seen updated (x, seen(x) + 1))
            (x::pair._1, pair._2)
          } else {
            //already seen more than max
            filterAfter(xs, seen)
          }
        case _ => (l, seen)//empty, terminate recursion
      }
    }
    //call inner recursive function
    filterAfter(l, seen, 2)._1
  }
```

Comment: Your recursive `filterAfter` don't need to return the state, you don't use it.

Comment: @Dimitri you are right. It was after 0:00, so that was not my most creative moment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is canonical Scala code to do reduce three or more in a row to two in a row:

```
  def checkForTwo(candidate: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    candidate match {
      case x :: y :: z :: tail if x == y && y == z =>
        checkForTwo(y :: z :: tail)
      case x :: tail => 
        x :: checkForTwo(tail)
      case Nil =>
        Nil
    }
  }
```

It looks at the first three elements of the list, and if they are the same, drops the first one and repeats the process. Otherwise, it passes items on through.

Comment: Nope. `checkForTwo(List(1, 2, 3, 1, 1))` returns `List(1, 2, 3, 1, 1)`

Comment: You are correct. I edited my answer to show that I was answering the second part of the question as the first part was something he already had answers for.

Comment: That, it does just great! Agreed.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with `groupBy` and filter, without any sorting (so it's O(N), sorting will give you additional O(Nlog(N)) in typical case):

```
val li = l1.zipWithIndex
val pred = li.groupBy(_._1).flatMap(_._2.lift(1)) //1 is your "2", but - 1
for ((x, i) <- li if !pred.get(x).exists(_ < i)) yield x
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer approach with immutable `Map`:

```
  def noMoreThan[T](list: List[T], max: Int): List[T] = {
    def go(tail: List[T], freq: Map[T, Int]): List[T] = {
      tail match {
        case h :: t =>
          if (freq(h) < max)
            h :: go(t, freq + (h -> (freq(h) + 1)))
          else go(t, freq)
        case _ => Nil
      }
    }
    go(list, Map[T, Int]().withDefaultValue(0))
  }
```